# Calling async function in lazy var property

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to call an async function from a lazy or computed property?

```
struct Item {
  lazy var name: String = {
    API.requestThing({ (string: String) in // Xcode didn't like this
      return string // this would not work here
    })
  }()
}

class API {
  class func requestThing(completion: String -> Void) {
    completion("string")
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't give a specific error but can't compile either.

Comment: Do you want to call the API just once and then cache the result? Otherwise you are calling the API every time.

Comment: There is no good reason to use "lazy" in this case. lazy is for initialization. Just create a normal func and pass a completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

Your completion handler in API.requestThing returns a String, yet it is supposed to have no return value:

```
(completion: String -> Void)
```

I got this to work:

```
struct Item {
    lazy var name: String = {
        API.requestThing({ (string: String) in 
            return string
        })
    }()
}

class API {
    class func requestThing(completion: String -> String) -> String {
        return completion("string")
    }
}
```

Comment: The function `requestThing` is _synchronous_ and not - as requested - asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

First, `requestThing` returns `()` (ie void) and not `String`. So the type of the following expression is also `()` and not `String`:

```
API.requestThing { string in
  return string
}
```

Second, the call to `requestThing` is asynchronous, so even if you defined `name` as a lazy var, the call to the var body function is still `synchronous`and will return immediately.

So if you can transform `name` into a function like this:

```
func name(completion: String -> ()) {
    API.requestThing { string in
        completion(string)
    }
}

// Later you call it in this way
myItem.name { name in
    // use the value of name
}
```

If in addition you want to cache the retrieved value you can modify `Item` to a `class` and use the following code

```
class Item {
    private var nameValue: String?
    func name(completion: String -> ()) {
        if let value = nameValue {
            // return cached value
            return completion(value)
        } else {
            // request value
            API.requestThing { string in
                // cache retrieved value
                self.nameValue = string
                // return retrieved value
                completion(string)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your solution, `name` is not a property anymore. And your caching approach suffers from a data race. That is, calling `name` will potentially invoke `API.requestThing` more than one time, and accessing `nameValue` is inherently unsafe due to the data race.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good reason to use "lazy" in this case. lazy is for initialization. Just create a normal func and pass a completion handler.

Comment: I can actually imagine use cases. For example, having a class `User` with a property `profileImage`. When fetching a user, the API returns a JSON with a _URL_ to the profile image. Class `User` internally keeps the URL and only starts to fetch the image when it is requested. This can be _safely_ implemented with a _future_. The property `profileImage ` becomes then a _lazy_ property of type `Future<UIImage>`.

Comment: Ok, but what is the obvious advantage to a normal function here? `func getProfileImage() -> Future<UIImage>`

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no compelling reason to do this, but the following approach seems to be reasonable:

Instead having a variable of type `String` - we sometimes require a "Future" of that thing, e.g. `Future<String>`. A future represents the *eventual* result of an asynchronous operation - that is exactly what's given in your question.

The future itself is a "normal" variable and can be lazy evaluated, too. It just doesn't yet have its eventual value. That means, the underlying task will only be started *when explicitly* requested (e.g. *lazily*). From a design or architectural point of view, this may make sense.

```
func fetchString() -> Future<String> { ... }

lazy var name: Future<String> = fetchString()
```

Later in your code, you obtain the variable as follows:

```
item.name.map { string in
    print(string)
}
```

If this is the first access to the lazy property, it will start the underlying asynchronous operation which calculates the string. Then, when the variable is available, the mapping function as provided in the `map` function will be called with the variable as an argument - possibly some time later, too.

Otherwise (if this is not the first access), it will just provide the string in the parameter when it is available, possibly immediately.

Since operations may fail, a "Future" also provides means to handle this:

```
item.name.map { string in
    print(string)
}.onFailure { error in
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises

There are implementations for Futures in Swift and Objective-C, also often called "Promise".

Comment: Actually using the Future pattern here could be quite dangerous, because: if you store the Future (for some reasons, otherwise why `lazy`?) the same Promise/Future would be returned on the next call to `lazy`. But as a Promise/Future per design is only allowed to resolve _exactly_ _once_ you could not do anything with it anymore. Trying to resolve it a second time would indeed in most Future/Promise implementations crash the app.

Comment: In fact, a future can be resolved (that is, completed) only once. By design, a future represents a _constant_, which is only available _after_ it has been completed. A client, which has obtained the future, can obtain its value more than one time, though. The class that _created_ the future, and which _exposes_ the property of type Future<T>, can create as many new futures, as it likes, if this is required or if this makes sense. It shouldn't be dangerous at all though.